# Pre-1990 book about exiled telepaths and a system of telepathic screening

Tags: story-identification, novel, space, telepathy

I read this as a teenager before 1991.

The story starts with a young man volunteering for a government position, or maybe being drafted.  Society does have some psionicists, but they are reviled, screened out through this mandatory testing, and exiled to a far away planet.

The protagonist is tagged as a telepath and sent to this colony, but he is absolutely sure he cannot receive anyone's thoughts, and starts out doubly exiled as he doesn't fit in with the other exiles that can all have various psychic abilities.  Turns out this guy is a powerful broadcaster, but cannot really "hear" others.  The exile colony tells him to stop "shouting" all the time.  And under stress he ends up activating teleportation abilities to save his new friends in the colony from a dangerous alien predator.

In the end, he returns back to take the role of director of the agency that screens for psionic abilities. It is revealed that the psions created the agency to find each other before the public could cause a witch hunt and sent all of these people to the colony to develop their powers, before returning some back to the homeworld to continue protecting and hiding people with psionic powers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this ***[The Beyond](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1349542.The_Beyond)*** (1967) by Jean and Jeff Sutton...?

> An agent, sent to a distant planet where those with telepathic powers are banished, and ordered to find the person with the ability to move objects by thought, discovers to his horror that he is telepathic.

A [review](http://sfreader.com/read_review.asp?t=The%20Beyond-by%20Jack%20and%20Jean%20Sutton&book=1585) I found provides some additional plot details, including the fact that one of the investigators sent to the colony turns out to be a type of telepath known as a 'transmitter.'

> The book opens with a Captain Cromwell of the smuggler Cosmic Wind landing on the exile colony of Engo. That world, soaked in the ghastly glow of its orange moon, holds a steadily decreasing population of miserable telepaths, condemned there by the Federation on behalf of a galaxy of those who fear the rape of their private thoughts by those with such powers.
>
> [...]
>
> Enter Alek Selby, investigator for the Social Administration Arm of the Federation, one arm of the galactic government controlling (read hunting and suppressing) telepaths.
>
> [...]
>
> **But Selby bears his own dreadful secret, which he has buried so long that he does not consciously acknowledge it. Selby bears the telepath taint, ignored and suppressed so long it barely functions. He is a transmitter. One who can project thoughts and impression on others so strongly he can delude them.**

Comment: Yes, this is it. The teleportation scene is when Selby and a boy called Johnny are attacked by an animal called a _groat_. Selby teleports himself and the boy (and the boy's dog) into a tree to escape the groat.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am thrilled to finally track this down.  And yes, this story is the one I remember!